# Floated Elements falling below floated input within UL in IE - Yet it's fine in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I've been working on this for about an hour now and I can't for the life of me determine why this is happening in IE.

I have the following HTML to show my registration form (excerpt):

```
<ul id="register_form_list">
    <li><label for="register_full_name" class="register_label">Full Name</label></li>
    <li class="input_wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="register_text_input" name="full_name" id="register_full_name" value="">
        <div class="register_field_help">
            <span class="register_field_error_text" style="display: none">Enter your first and last name</span>
        </div>
            <div class="register_field_error">
        <span class="register_field_error_text">Please enter your full name</span>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following CSS, for showing my registration elements and 'tool tips' that I have created:

```
ul#register_form_list { float: left; clear: left; margin: 25px 0 0 29px; width: 670px; }
ul#register_form_list li { float: left; clear: left; display: inline; margin-left:0px; }
ul#register_form_list li.input_wrapper { padding: 0 0 15px 0; }
label.register_label { float: left; font-size: 0.9em; font-weight: bold; color: #093C5D; text-decoration: none; }
ul#register_form_list input.register_text_input { float: left; clear: left; margin: 6px 0 0 0; padding: 5px; width: 260px; border: #B0B0B0 1px solid; background: #FFFFFF url(images/quizmaker/field_shadow_bg.png) repeat-x; background-position: top; outline: none; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
ul#register_form_list input.register_submit { float: left; clear: left; margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px; }
div.register_field_help { float: left; display: none; margin: 0 0 0 6px; width: 386px; height: 39px; background: url(images/welcome/register_text_help.png) top left no-repeat; }
span.register_field_help_text { float: left; margin: 10px 0 0 20px; color: #FFFFFF; }
div.register_field_error { float: left; margin: 0 0 0 6px; width: 386px; height: 39px; background: url(images/welcome/register_text_error.png) top left no-repeat; }
span.register_field_error_text { float: left; margin: 10px 0 0 20px; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

For some reason the `div.register_field_error` toop tip elements that are showing are dropping below my `input` fields, when I would like them to display side by side.

It is working fine in Chrome, there is enough width within my `ul` to accommodate the tooltips (670px), but I have to adjust the `ul` to `width: 733px` or more within the developer tools to make them appear side by side in IE.

The code is [live here](http://uquiz.com/welcome), just click 'Register' without filling in any of the input elements and the tooltips appear by each input element.

It's as if the UL has some right hand padding on it, but I've tried `margin:0` and `padding:0` on the UL to test and that hasn't worked.

**It would appear that this issue is happening when I have IE11 emulating IE7.  I would like the site to work in IE7**

[image]

Comment: [What do you mean](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ztsJ0.png)?

Comment: Please see the screenshot I've added to the question.  Is that in IE11 too?

Comment: The screenshot I linked is from IE11 on Windows 8.1, it also looks the same with IE9 emulation.

Comment: I've got my 'Document mode' set to 7, because it says it's the default :/.  Is that not the right setting?  If I set it to 'Edge' it would appear that it is fine.

Comment: Edge is the 'IE11' mode. It appears to be a problem in IE7 then.

Comment: Yes, it appears it's IE7 emulated.  Please help to fix for IE7 if anyone has any experience with these kinds of issues

Comment: I would recommend 2 things, visit http://modern.ie and get a free virtual machine for IE 7 to actually test to be certain. 2nd, you are going to have to use a completely different stylesheet for IE 7. Remember IE 7 was released around 8 years ago and the way CSS worked then was much different than today. So you are going to have to apply much different styles to make it layout as desired compared to modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved away from using floats, they are an unnecessary evil for general layouts.  Using floats takes your floated elements out of the flow of the document, when they can be quite easily achieved without doing this.

I am now using `display: inline-block` and `display: table` for layouts such as the example I provided.

I have completely stripped 'float' and 'clear' out of my CSS, except for times where I might want some text to wrap around an image.  I'm pretty sure that this is what `float` was originally intended for.